# Java MouseListener entered and exited don't update unless I alt tab

Tags: java, exit, mouselistener, enter

I have those 2 functions

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    int mx = e.getX();
    int my = e.getY();

    if(mouseOver(mx, my, Game.WIDTH / 2 - 285, Game.HEIGHT / 2 - 170, Game.hud.materials[1].getWidth(), Game.hud.materials[1].getHeight()))
        isOnMaterial[0] = true;

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    int mx = e.getX();
    int my = e.getY();

    if(!mouseOver(mx, my, Game.WIDTH / 2 - 285, Game.HEIGHT / 2 - 170, Game.hud.materials[1].getWidth(), Game.hud.materials[1].getHeight()))
        isOnMaterial[0] = false;

}
```

The `mouseOver` is a function which I use to set the perimeter which the mouse needs to be in to trigger something.

So when I indeed enter that area, the variable is set to true, and if it is true, a rectangle is drawn with Graphics. That rectangle won't draw though unless I alt tab the window, which is set to full screen like this:

```
jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
jf.setUndecorated(true);
```

This applied to the `mouseExited` function as well. So when I alt tab in, I see that the rectangle is drawn, and when the mouse exists that area the rectangle is still drawn unless I alt tab again.

Also I know that the problem is on those 2 functions because I tried to `System.Out.Println()` something when the event is triggered and it only prints on the console once after I alt tab, and I have one more `System.Out.Println()` on the function which I draw the rectangle and it keeps printing all the time after I alt tab, not only once. (Because of the game loop)

I hope my problem is clear, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` are only called when the mouse goes in or out of your component as a whole. You can't use it to check whether the mouse has entered a particular part of your component. For that, instead of `MouseListener`, you should use `mouseMoved` in `MouseMotionListener`.

```
class ... implements MouseMotionListener {
    //...

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        int mx = e.getX();
        int my = e.getY();
        int hudX = Game.WIDTH / 2 - 285;
        int hudY = Game.HEIGHT / 2 - 170;
        int hudW = Game.hud.materials[1].getWidth();
        int hudH = Game.hud.materials[1].getHeight();
        isOnMaterial[0] = mouseOver(mx, my, hudX, hudY, hudW, hudH);
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't really notify whether the cursor entered or left the area, it just checks whether the cursor is currently in it.

P.S. Use constants with meaningful names in your code. Magic numbers like the 285 and 170 above are bad practice.